# How can I see where the results from my COALESCE statement have been retrieved from?

Tags: sql, ssms, coalesce

I have five fields which I need to look at: `FirstName`, `Surname`, `DateOfBirth`, `id` and `Postcode`.

If I run this (using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)):

```
SELECT COALESCE(FirstName, Surname, DateOfBirth, id, Postcode)
FROM table1
```

It returns results like this:

```
1.  DAVID
2.  SUSAN
3.  764329
4.  FRANK
5.  STEPHANIE
6.  HARRIS
7.  10/10/1967
8.  E3 5QP
9.  DAVID
10. JOHN
```

The trouble with this is that it isn't always easy to determine where the results come from.  For example, `DAVID` and `JOHN` could easily be first names or surnames.

Is there a way to see the origin of each result?  Something like this:

```
1.  DAVID FirstName
2.  SUSAN FirstName
3.  764329 id
4.  FRANK FirstName
5.  STEPHANIE FirstName
6.  HARRIS Surname
7.  10/10/1967 DateOfBirth
8.  E3 5QP Postcode
9.  DAVID Surname
10. JOHN Surname
```

Perhaps two columns of results would be good: one with the result, and one with the origin.

Comment: The only way to get that is by creating a new column with ```CASE WHEN xxx is not NULL then 'source'``` based on the ```Coalesce``` hierarchy.

Comment: Not exactly true.. you can use `CONCAT` @manibharataraju

Comment: You are right. My motive was to say that u have to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify RDBMS, but if you really want to use `coalesce` then you can try something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(FirstName,' First Name'), CONCAT(Surname,' Surname'),...)
FROM table1
```

Use `CONCAT` or a specific way of your RDBMS to concatenate. `CONCAT` should return null if one of the elemets in null, so it should work the same.

You can also generate a new column using `CASE EXPRESSION` as @manibharataraju suggested in the comments.

Comment: This returns `DAVIDDAVID`, `SUSANSUSAN`, `764329764329` and so on.

Comment: @Mus Then you didn't use parenthesis around the second element of `CONCAT`. Look at the code `CONCAT(FirstName," First Name")`. The second arguments is a string, not a column name.

Comment: I copied it precisely as per your example: `COALESCE(CONCAT(FirstName, "FirstName")...)` and so on. If I add a space after the first quotation mark, as per your example, it returns an error about an invalid column name.

Comment: Your using sql server? This is why it is important to specifiy your rdbms! Try replacing `"` into `'` --> `CONCAT(FirstName,' First Name')`

Comment: Yes, I am and that's it - thank you. I'll update the question too.